# Corrupt theme file unrecognized magic number: 0 [CodenameOne]

Tags: themes, codenameone

Why am getting below error in codename one while running or opening theme file. please provide solution on same.

```
java.io.IOException: Corrupt theme file unrecognized magic number: 0
com.svastikagames.gkquiz.MyApplication.start() Error java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.openFileImpl(Resources.java:332)
at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.openFile(Resources.java:261)
at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.<init>(Resources.java:181)
at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.open(Resources.java:729)
at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.openLayered(Resources.java:694)
at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.openLayered(Resources.java:658)
at generated.StateMachineBase.startApp(StateMachineBase.java:59)
at generated.StateMachineBase.<init>(StateMachineBase.java:31)
at generated.StateMachineBase.<init>(StateMachineBase.java:124)
at userclasses.StateMachine.<init>(StateMachine.java:236)
at com.svastikagames.gkquiz.MyApplication.start(MyApplication.java:25)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.codename1.impl.javase.Executor$1$1.run(Executor.java:100)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1149)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:966)
at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually this error means the file is 0 length and got corrupted at some point due to an unclear reason.

If the file is of 0 length there is nothing we can do to help recover its content unless you are using the XML team mode.

If you are using that then just launch the designer tool from command line and edit the theme it should actually work since it loads the resources from the XML's under the res directory and not the res file itself. If it prints out errors during save these might help you narrow down the problem and you can also refer these errors to us.

In order to launch the designer from command line use this on Unix/Linux/Mac:

```
java -jar ~/.codenameone/designer_1.jar
```

And on Windows:

```
java -jar MY_USER_DIRECTORY\.codenameone\designer_1.jar
```

Comment: I replace theme.rec file with my backup file and need to add many more components again. please let me know the way to use xml team mode, so if same is happen again then am secure with this types of damages.

Comment: method of saving changes may not properly done. I notice that when we close designer suddenly (due to hang or something) when file may be under save process that time this problem occurs.

Comment: We rename the file on save to create a transaction. If you have a case where something consistently fails please try to reproduce it from command line and post potential stacks you get in such a case.